# JBoss 4.2.3 - how to find path to jar file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss

I'm getting an error in a JBOSS application:

Static Method [addHeader] not found on JavaBean [class com.ppnet.webservice.WebserviceHeaderWriter]

I have checked the WebserviceHeaderWriter.jar that gets deployed into JBOSS and checked it in eclipse. It looks as if it should have this method on it.

I think that the JBoss application might be loading a different version of the WebserviceHeaderWriter.jar without this method on it, is there a way to check the location of the file that is getting loaded?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do this by adding -verbose:class to my JVM options